# OpenGL shader binaries failing to link upon adding multiple outputs

Tags: opengl, linker, glsl, shader, linker-errors

I'm working on an OpenGL application and my shader binaries compiler properly, but fail to link and I can't find a reason. They fail to link when I add a third output to my shader. So my essential questions are:

- Why is the linker failing when I add three or more outputs (the third being buffer2)
- How to find linker errors like these in the future.

I'm using spirv-cross and shaderc to convert a vulkan shader to an opengl shader to an opengl binary.

My debug won't give me any info either:

```
---------------
Debug message (1): SHADER_ID_LINK error has been generated. GLSL link failed for program 1, "Test Shader":
Source: Shader Compiler
Type: Error
Severity: high

---------------
Debug message (1282): Error has been generated. GL error GL_INVALID_OPERATION in UseProgram: (ID: 1001309929) Generic error
Source: API
Type: Error
Severity: high
```

I've posted my code in a gist as well as below. https://gist.github.com/KarimIO/e6b9716ce491cfdfe74196e426376bf5

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 450

layout(binding = 0, std140) uniform EngineUbo
{
    mat4 proj;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 model;
} ubo;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition;
layout(location = 0) out vec3 fragmentPosition;
layout(location = 1) out vec3 fragmentNormal;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexNormal;
layout(location = 2) out vec3 fragmentTangent;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 vertexTangent;
layout(location = 3) out vec2 fragmentTexCoord0;
layout(location = 3) in vec2 vertexTexCoord0;

void main()
{
    vec4 posVec4 = ubo.model * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
    gl_Position = (ubo.proj * ubo.view) * posVec4;
    fragmentPosition = posVec4.xyz;
    fragmentNormal = vertexNormal;
    fragmentTangent = vertexTangent;
    fragmentTexCoord0 = vertexTexCoord0;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 450

layout(binding = 1, std140) uniform MaterialUbo
{
    vec4 color;
} materialUbo;

layout(binding = 2) uniform sampler2D albedoTexture;
layout(binding = 3) uniform sampler2D normalTexture;
layout(binding = 4) uniform sampler2D metalnessTexture;
layout(binding = 5) uniform sampler2D roughnessTexture;

layout(location = 3) in vec2 fragmentTexCoord0;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 fragmentNormal;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 fragmentTangent;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 gbuffer0;
layout(location = 0) in vec3 fragmentPosition;
layout(location = 1) out vec4 gbuffer1;
layout(location = 2) out vec4 gbuffer2;

vec3 TransformNormalToWorldSpace(vec3 vertexNormalValue, vec3 normalTextureSample, vec3 vertexTangentValue)
{
    vec3 bumpMapNormal = normalTextureSample;
    if (all(equal(normalTextureSample, vec3(0.0))))
    {
        return vertexNormalValue;
    }
    vec3 newNormal = normalize(vertexNormalValue);
    vec3 newTangent = normalize(vertexTangentValue);
    newTangent = normalize(newTangent - (newNormal * dot(newTangent, newNormal)));
    vec3 bitangent = cross(newTangent, newNormal);
    bumpMapNormal = (bumpMapNormal * 2.0) - vec3(1.0);
    bumpMapNormal = vec3(-bumpMapNormal.xy, bumpMapNormal.z);
    mat3 tangentBitangentNormalMatrix = mat3(vec3(newTangent), vec3(bitangent), vec3(newNormal));
    return normalize(tangentBitangentNormalMatrix * bumpMapNormal);
}

void main()
{
    vec4 albedo = materialUbo.color * texture(albedoTexture, fragmentTexCoord0);
    vec3 textureSpaceNormal = texture(normalTexture, fragmentTexCoord0).xyz;
    float metalness = texture(metalnessTexture, fragmentTexCoord0).x;
    float roughness = texture(roughnessTexture, fragmentTexCoord0).x;
    vec3 specular = mix(vec3(0.039999999105930328369140625), albedo.xyz, vec3(metalness));
    vec3 param = fragmentNormal;
    vec3 param_1 = textureSpaceNormal;
    vec3 param_2 = fragmentTangent;
    vec3 worldSpaceNormal = TransformNormalToWorldSpace(param, param_1, param_2);
    gbuffer0 = vec4(fragmentPosition, 1.0);
    gbuffer1 = vec4(worldSpaceNormal, 1.0);
    gbuffer2 = albedo;
}
```

Edit: This is only happening on Intel Drivers, not Nvidia. But I need to fix it anyways.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. There is nothing wrong with this program. Are the shader objects created with the correct types (`GL_VERTEX_SHADER`, `GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER`)?

Comment: Check the actual info log of the program object you attempted to link.

Comment: @Rabbid76 yeah that's the annoying part, the program seems correct and the shaders are the correct types!

Comment: @derhass The program is marked as invalid but i can't access the log, it's empty

Comment: @Rabbid76 I noticed it's only on my Intel integrated gpu, do you have one?